# Recognizing special keys without taking over the screen

Tags: c, unix, ncurses, terminfo

In a program that uses the `curses` or `ncurses` library, the `getch()` function can recognize either an ordinary character (like `'x'`) or the escape sequence sent by the arrow and function keys. For example, typing the up arrow key might send the sequence (Escape, '[', 'A'), but `getch()` will return the `int` value `KEY_UP`.  It even uses timing information to distinguish between an Escape character sent by itself and an Escape character that's part of a sequence.

To use `getch()` successfully, you first have to call `initscr()`, which clears the screen so that curses can control what's displayed.

Is there a convenient way to recognize special keys *without* taking over the screen? Ideally I'd like to call `getch()` without first calling `initscr()`, and have it return the same value it would have returned if I had called `initscr()`, but experiment indicates that doesn't work.

Here's a non-working example of what I'm trying to do. The program prompts the user to enter Up, Down, Escape, Left, Right, and conforms that the correct keys were entered.

Running the program with `-c` invokes `initscr()` and allows it to work correctly. Running it without `-c` calls `getch()` without first calling `initscr()`; all the `getch()` calls fail without waiting for input, returning `ERR` (`-1`).

```
// gcc arrows.c -o arrows -lncurses
#include <term.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int use_curses = 0;
    if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "-c") == 0) {
        use_curses = 1;
    }
    else if (argc != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-c]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    WINDOW *win;
    if (use_curses) {
        win = initscr();
        cbreak();
        noecho();
        nonl();
        intrflush(stdscr, FALSE);
        keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
        mvaddstr(0, 0, "Press UP, DOWN, Escape, LEFT, RIGHT");
    }
    else {
        puts("Press UP, DOWN, Escape, LEFT, RIGHT");
    }

    int keys[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
        keys[i] = getch();
    }
    int ok;
    if (keys[0] == KEY_UP &&
        keys[1] == KEY_DOWN &&
        keys[2] == '\x1b' &&
        keys[3] == KEY_LEFT &&
        keys[4] == KEY_RIGHT)
    {
        ok = 1;
        if (use_curses) {
            mvaddstr(2, 0, "OK");
        }
        else {
            puts("OK");
        }
    }
    else {
        ok = 0;
        char message[100];
        sprintf(message,
                "Incorrect input: (%d, %d, %d, %d, %d)",
                keys[0], keys[1], keys[2], keys[3], keys[4]);
        if (use_curses) {
            mvaddstr(2, 0, message);
        }
        else {
            puts(message);
        }
    }
    if (use_curses) {
        mvaddstr(4, 0, "Press any key to quit ");
        (void)getch();
        endwin();
    }
    exit(ok ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The output without the `-c` option (on Ubuntu 17.04 x86_64) is:

```
Press UP, DOWN, Escape, LEFT, RIGHT
Incorrect input: (-1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
```

**UPDATE**: A solution using something other than curses would be fine. It would have to use terminfo, directly or indirectly, to know what input sequences to look for. (It seems to me that recognizing special key inputs should be straightforward and *not* intimately tied to taking over the entire screen.)

Comment: No time to do an answer, but maybe `man 3 termcap` is connected to what you want

Comment: The curses library doesn't provide such code, AFAIK.  You'd have to fettle your own use of the terminal attributes.  You might find (some of) the discussion in [How to distinguish between escape and escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039759/) useful.  One part of the problem is defining codes for key sequences.  Another part is identifying key sequences.   Most of the rest is more-or-less mechanical coding.

Answer (score 3):

The [`filter`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-filter_nofilter) function, called before [`initscr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr), tells curses to use a single line (rather than the whole screen).  There is an example of its use (named "filter") in [ncurses-examples](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html), which consists of a command-prompt.

`getch` updates at least *part* of the screen, e.g., when it echoes the input.  That update can affect either just a line (using `filter`), or the whole screen.  If you're clever, you can turn off echo, and (since `filter` suppresses the screen erasure), pretend that it updates nothing at all.  For example, you could redirect the output to `/dev/null` by initializing curses with `newterm`.

Echoing input is only part of the story: curses does initialize the screen, and the associated `refresh` done by `getch` would make that hard to avoid in a portable way.  There's an ncurses-specific option in the sample program which works around unwanted switching between normal/alternate screens, which could occur during screen-initialization.

Here's a screenshot of "filter", demonstrating that it does not take over the whole screen.  The inverse video is due to ncurses initializing colors (white-on-black), but as the help-message indicates, that's configurable.  Without making a movie, it's hard to demonstrate that it handles special keys, but reading the [source code](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/test/filter.c) should be enough.

[image: example of filter program]